# Distinguish Swipe from Touch in Spritekit - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touch, gesture

I am currently working on an arcade app where the user taps for the sprite to jump over an obstacle and swipes down for it to slide under an obstacle. My problem is that when I begin a swipe the touchesBegan function is called so the sprite jumps instead of sliding. Is there a way to distinguish these two?

Comment: use gestures to distinguish

Comment: But I want to tap not perform some gesture

Comment: ... tap is a gesture, so is a swipe

Comment: I modified my code using a tap gesture but now the action occurs when the tap ends. My goal is for the action to occur once I begin the tap

Comment: then you can't tell the difference between a tap and a swipe,  can't predict the future lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a gestures state to fine tune user interaction. Gestures are coordinated, so shouldn't interfere with each other.

```
func handlePanFrom(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state != .changed {
        return
    }

    // Handle pan here
}

func handleTapFrom(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state != .ended {
        return
    }

    // Handle tap here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a slight delay for your touch controls? I have a game where I do something similar using a SKAction with delay. Optionally you can set a location property to give your self a bit of wiggle room with the touchesMoved method incase someone has a twitchy finger (thanks KnightOfDragon)

```
let jumpDelayKey = "JumpDelayKey"
var startingTouchLocation: CGPoint?

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        // starting touch location
        startingTouchLocation = location

        // start jump delay
        let action1 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.05)
        let action2 = SKAction.run(jump)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([action1, action2])
        run(sequence, withKey: jumpDelayKey)
    }
}

func jump() {
   // your jumping code
}
```

Just make sure the delay is not too long so that your controls dont feel unresponsive. Play around with the value for your desired result.

Than in your touches moved method you remove the SKAction if your move threshold has been reached

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        guard let startingTouchLocation = startingTouchLocation else { return }

        // adjust this value of how much you want to move before continuing
        let adjuster: CGFloat = 30

        guard location.y < (startingTouchLocation.y - adjuster) ||
              location.y > (startingTouchLocation.y + adjuster) ||
              location.x < (startingTouchLocation.x - adjuster) ||
              location.x > (startingTouchLocation.x + adjuster) else {
```

return }

```
        // Remove jump action
        removeAction(forKey: jumpDelayKey)

        // your sliding code
    }
}
```

You could play around with Gesture recognisers although I am not sure that will work and how it affects the responder chain.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not a viable answer,  you would need to add in thresholds and track the touch movements.  What if somebody has a twitchy finger?  To that user, they are touching, but to the code, they are moving their finger

Comment: Thats true, I just added  the additional location check.

Comment: Hmm,  what happens when you move over a sprite that has touch enabled?  do you lose the touchmoved calls?

Comment: I gave you the upvote,  the only thing I would be concerned with now as a developer is that people get used to the timing of how things register on ios devices, just make sure that the wait period matches it

Comment: Is there a better way in your opinion? Im not sure how gesture recognisers interact with touches methods. I actually noticed that you need this sort check if you have a 3d touch enabled phone and use touches moved. On 3d touch enabled phones touches moved is called even if the location has not changed. Its so annoying and took me ages to figure out. I have a game where I am doing something similar, tap to shoot, move to enter slow motion. On 3d touch devices hooting never worked till we figured out that touches moved gets basically called immedialty. I am using this check and it seems to work.

Comment: Dont you usually have separate touch code for nodes with touch enabled e.g in the subclass of that node.

Comment: yes there is separate code, that is why I asked.  What if we are touching next to a sprite, and we go into it.  Your remove code will not fire, so the character will jump instead of recognizing a swipe

Comment: I have never dealt with 3D touch,  i really need to get a device that has it,  thank you for mentioning that so I can add it to my notes

Comment: I haven't noticed a problem yet with node subclasses, eg. my buttons. I keep an eye out for that tho. For the 3d touch thing have a look at that question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060423/swift-spritekit-3d-touch-and-touches-moved